# Parse Javascript fetch in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm calling a post request through Javascript and here's how it looks,

```
function syncDeviceId(deviceID, mod){
  var request = new Request('url', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        uuid: unique_id,
    }),
    mode: 'cors'
  })

  fetch(request).then(function(data) {
    return
  })
```

And I'm trying to retreive the values like this,

```
<?php

$post['uuid'] = $_POST['uuid']; 

?>
```

This is returned as empty, how can I retrieve the values from the fetch post request in PHP. Thanks

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your PHP code. What does the actual network request look like in your browser's debug tools?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked the request going out properly?

Answer (score 20):

This is because you are not setting [Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request)'s body to the correct format.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request#Parameters
>
> body: Any body that you want to add to your request: this can be a
>   Blob, BufferSource, FormData, URLSearchParams, or USVString object.
>   Note that a request using the GET or HEAD method cannot have a body.

[The content-type header is based on the object set to `body`, or to the Content-Type specified in a Header object if supplied.](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-bodyinit-extract)

So setting body to a JSON string makes the content-type header be `text/plain`. Even if you set the request Content-Type to `application/json` it wouldn't matter because PHP does not by default know how to parse incoming JSON request payloads (unless it was recently added in PHP 7).

You can do a couple things client side

Create a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object from your object, and use that as body, and a `multipart/form` content-type will be used

```
var data = {some:"data",even:"more"};
var fd = new FormData();
//very simply, doesn't handle complete objects
for(var i in data){
   fd.append(i,data[i]);
}
var req = new Request("url",{
   method:"POST",
   body:fd,
   mode:"cors"
});
```

Create a [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object which will set the content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Note: URLSearchParams is not widely supported

```
//Similar to creating a simple FormData object
var data = {some:"data",even:"more"};
var params = new URLSearchParams();
for(i in data){
   params.append(i,data[i]);
}
var req = new Request("url",{
   method:"POST",
   body:params,
   mode:"cors"
});
```

Create a query string (ie `a=hello&b=world`) and use a [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers) object to set Content-Type to `application/x-form-urlencoded`

```
var data = {some:"data",even:"more"};
var headers = new Headers({
    "Content-Type":"application/x-form-urlencoded"
});
var params = [];
for(i in data){
   params.push(i + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[i]));
}
var req = new Request("url",{
   method:"POST",
   body:params.join("&"),
   headers:headers,
   mode:"cors"
});
```

If you still want to send a JSON payload instead of doing the above you can, but you will have to read the raw request input and then use json_decode to get to the data

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: The very last method you mentioned always returns an empty string for me.

Comment: @LonnieBest, If `file_get_contents('php://input')` is returning an empty string then your POST request didn't send a request body

Answer (score 4):

I too was having the same issue.

I used Chrome debug tool first to make sure that I was passing on a Request Body (Which the chrome debug will call "Request Payload")
I was sending

```
{ClientDomain: "example.com"}
```

I then used the stated code in my receiving PHP script.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
```

which then put my JSON code into an array which I could then read in PHP.

```
PRINT $data["ClientDomain"];
```

I hope this helps the next guy.

Answer (score -1):

You need to echo your result, so it will be returned in the body of your request:

```
<?php

$post['uuid'] = $_POST['uuid']; 
echo $post['uuid'];
?>
```

Additionally, it looks like you need to instantiate your request object with the url of the php script you're calling:

`var request = new Request('my_script.php', { . . .`

Wherever your php script is.

Comment: Well I used print_r and the result was Array
(
    [uuid] => 
)

Comment: If it's your code above, your's passing your request to 'url'. That needs to be the php script you're actually calling. I will ammend my answer for this.

Comment: It is a php script I just removed the real url and replaced it with 'url'

Comment: I'm assuming you replaced it for the purposes of posting this question. Since, you're echoing results, let's just assume you're getting a 200 response. What is the output of `print_r($_POST)`? What is the structure of your `data` argument in the promise callback?