# Fetch doesn't send post data

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I'm having this problem, where for some reason I can't send data to another PHP script with POST over the `fetch` API.

I've already checked other solutions and cleaned up my code, but it still won't work.

Maybe I'm missing something.

Here's my code:

```js
function request(where, num, last, query){
 for (var i = num; i > 0; i--) {
  fetch("global/modul.php", {
   method: "POST",
   body: JSON.stringify({
    last: last,
    query: query
   }),
   headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   }
  }).then(function (response) {
   return response.text();
  }).then(function (data) {
   let html = data.trim();
   document.getElementById(where).innerHTML += html.trim();
  }).catch(function (error) {
   console.log('Request failed', error);
  });

  last = document.getElementById(where).lastChild.id;
 }
}
```

```php
    var_dump($_POST);
```

Prints:

> array(0) { }

I've also tested the solutions shown in [Parse Javascript fetch in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091757/parse-javascript-fetch-in-php), but it didn't solve the problem. I still don't get the POST data in my php-script.

Comment: Can you see what is actually sent in the network tab of the developer console?

Comment: @solarc yes, last null
query top

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no problem with your JS code. However you need to look for the data in another variable in your PHP code, by reading `php://input` like so:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508364/2831645

Comment: And this is because...? Its just a normal POST, isn't it?

Comment: @putvande is it a genuine question or you're hinting thibpat to improve their answer? :-)

Comment: Genuine question. I don't see why `var_dump($_POST)` doesn't work.

Comment: @putvande because php only decodes `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` automatically